# SSH error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: windows, ssh

I have a website hosted on a remote, shared server. I am on Windows and am trying to SSH in to my host from the Git Bash command line. I've created a new RSA key of size 4096 via cPanel and authorized it. I downloaded the public and private keys and added the key to my ssh config file:

`IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey_rsa`

When I issue the command `ssh -vvv user@something.com` I get an error.

`OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to something.com [174.37.199.18] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Me/.ssh/acquia_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Me/.ssh/acquia_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Me/.ssh/mykey_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Me/.ssh/mykey_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

How do I troubleshoot this? What's more, how do I do so on Windows, without a full complement of Unix-based command-line tools? Basically the tools I have are Git Bash, the Windows command line, cPanel, and I can FTP into my server with Filezilla or from the Windows command line.

Comment: The remote server is deciding to drop your connection immediately after it's made. It has nothing to do with your keys or your home directory permissions. You need to investigate the logs and configuration on the remote ssh server.

Comment: How might I do that?